# What is a font that is also a French word?

Tags: vocabulaire

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104673/first-riddle-attempt

There is a riddle that asks for a font that is a French word but is also known by English speakers. Can you suggest some possibilities for this. Thanks.

Comment: Since the wording of riddles is so often a factor, would you mind posting the riddle itself?

Comment: You would need someone to deliver it if this question is on topic.  Might be a better fit for Puzzling SE.

Comment: Was it this one?  Please note when your posting references another stack. 
 https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104673/first-riddle-attempt/104716#104716

Comment: Yes that is it...

Comment: I just have not the best french.

Comment: You're basically asking us for the answer to this riddle, isn't this cheating a bit? :)

Comment: I am not looking for the answer just some possibilities!

Comment: If you don't want to help that is ok. But just to tell you using google is allowed for solving these puzzles.

Comment: If that's okay by Puzzling SE's policy, then no problem for me! So far I didn't find anything, but if I manage to find the answer, be sure I'll let you know. :)

Comment: By the way, the puzzle doesn't say that the word has to be a *font*. It says "some fancy English typographers refer to it", so you should also try to broaden your search a bit.

Comment: I wrote a previous answer to the question which hinted at the fact that I was on the right trail of thinking.

Comment: For the record the answer to the riddle was 'arobase'

Comment: @vc74 Chapeau !

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't help with French...

Comment: @livresque Thanks! This riddle is much more easy when you speak French

Answer (score 2):

I went through this [list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/windows_10_font_list) and found these fonts that would made sense if pronounced in French.

The most probable one is **courier**, in French an almost similar word *courrier* means *mail* or **Symbol** that means literally the same thing but written with **e** (symbole), there is also **Trebuchet** which is an homonym to **trébucher** meaning *stumble* in French.

Other fonts that could pass as French words are the **noms propres** like Georgia, Himalaya, Tahoma, ...

Comment: Please note that "trébuchet" is also a French word in itself, with the same meaning as in English.

Comment: Ok thank you!!!!

Comment: Do you know any french words that start with meme...

Comment: If it is another question unrelated to this, it should be asked on its own page to help others searching for the same thing.

Comment: *Courier* is not a French word, *courrier* is!